# The text align is not working

Tags: html, css

The `text-align:center` is not working. Please help me out. Why is it not working?

That's the HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Wheat and Barley</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Helvetica;">

     <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <h1 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center; background-color:blue;">
        Wheat
        </h1>
     </div>
     <p>Wheat is a cereal grain...</p>
     <p>This grain...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Because H1 is inside an inline block element.

Comment: Would you please provide me an answer?

Comment: That **is** the answer. You are centering the text (h1) within a div that is **inline-block**, so h1 is getting centered within the div itself, while the div is not at the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Make use of center tag

Surround the div like this -

`<center><div> ... </div></center>`

It works, the color will stay behind the text only! Also it'd be centered!

Thanks.

Comment: Umm..thatt doesn't help me.  You see I **must** use inline-block in my coding. I can't spread the colour all around. The width must be set to the width of the total text.

Comment: Why not surround the `<div>` with a `<center>` Like this - `<center><div>...</div></center>`! Try that! I tried! It works!

Answer (score 1):

Text align work fine, but display inline-block elements are like inline elements but they can have a width and a height. 
If you don't assign  width the div as wide as the text.

Simply remove inline-block, div element is already display block.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Wheat and Barley</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Helvetica;">

    <div><h1 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center; background-color:blue;">Wheat</h1></div>

     <p>Wheat is a cereal grain, originally from the Levant region of the Near East but now cultivated worldwide. In 2013, world production of wheat was 713 million tons, making it the third most-produced cereal after maize (1,016 million tons) and rice (745 million tons). Wheat was the second most-produced cereal in 2009; world production in that year was 682 million tons, after maize, and with rice as a close third.</p>

     <p>This grain is grown on more land area than any other commercial food. World trade in wheat is greater than for all other crops combined. Globally, wheat is the leading source of vegetable protein in human food, having a higher protein content than other major cereals, maize (corn) or rice. In terms of total production tonnages used for food, it is currently second to rice as the main human food crop and ahead of maize, after allowing for maize's more extensive use in animal feeds. The archaeological record suggests that this first occurred in the regions known as the Fertile Crescent.</p>



 </body>

</html>
```

If possible don't use inlene CSS but in external file. For reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Umm..thatt doesn't help me. You see I must use inline-block in my coding.

Comment: Look at the code. Remove display inline block and the h1 is centered to the page. If you need inline-block element add at that element width 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can Add width:100% to h1 style and can remove div..

```
<h1 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center; background-color:blue; width:100%">Wheat</h1>
```

Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9fyk3ee8/1/)

**EDIT :**

Do you want like this ? Just Check Updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qpg2p4bj/)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to everybody who has so far answered this question. @HMGtbOfficial's post proved most helpful among all others. As per his suggestion, I put the `<div>` in the center. Hopefully, this works! A big, fat thanks to him. Thanks for helping me out!

I rewrote the HTML code as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
   <title>Wheat and Barley</title>
</head>

<body style="font-family:Helvetica;">

     <div style="display:inline-block; text-align:center;">
        <h1 style="font-weight:bold; background-color:blue;">
        Wheat
        </h1>
     </div>
     <p>Wheat is a cereal grain...</p>
     <p>This grain...</p>
</body>

</html>
```